# Automatically open an app within iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm currently developing an app for iOS and I've got a list of PDF files in the app which I want to be able to open (and show).

Now I do know you can do that with the [UIDocumentInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html), which then shows what apps are able to open the specific file, but I'm looking for a solution where I can open an app (e.g. Adobe Reader) without first having to open the UIDocumentInteractionController, tapping the app I want and then opening it.

Is this possible? And if so: how?

Thanks in advance!

DckWlff

Comment: Adobe Reader doesn't support URL Schemes yet, but you can use other apps to open pdfs using URL Schemes.

Comment: I have seen people say that on the internet yes, but that was about a year ago. Do they still not support that?

Comment: @jcesar is right. Have a look at this: http://forums.adobe.com/message/4378443
But I didn't heard of any special feature or quality of adobe reader. So why not use the share sheet so your users can choose or use the default quicklook viewer.

Comment: Yes, that was the topic I meant (which I had seen). I tried both the _com.adobe.reader.request_ and _com.adobe.Adobe-Reader_ schemes (which I found on the link you provided) but the first only opens the app and does nothing after that. The point of opening a specific app was that the client for which I am developing the app wanted it that way. So it seems I have to find another way around it.

Comment: You have to use the "open with" option, open the PDFs inside your app or use another app, I think good reader supports URL Schemes. I think the best option is opening the PDFs inside your app, in a webview for example: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1630.html

Comment: OK, the UIWebview seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at URL Schemes. But the app you want to open needs to support it.
http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

You can open an app in your App like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myapp://"]];
```

Edit:
You can find some schemes here: http://schemes.zwapp.com